# Detecting the running of all tests, versus one test or a class, from eventTestPhaseStart?

Tags: grails, ant, groovy, junit

I want this:

```
eventTestPhaseStart = { name ->
    ant.sequential {
        clean()
    }
}
```

to only run when I run `grails test-app` to test all tests at once, and NOT before each test is run individuall or as a class (like from an IDE). Is there an easy way to modify this to detect this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at `$GRAILS_HOME/scripts/_GrailsTest.groovy`, the event to hook onto should be `TestPhasesStart` instead of `TestPhaseStart` (not the plural form).

Comment: This still seems to run when running individual tests through IntelliJ.